Triangle Inequality
Hi I'm going through the fundamentals of mathematics and have trouble understanding this.
Reproduced here:
A convergent sequence can tend to only one limit. For suppose $a_n \to l$
and $a_n \to m$, where $l \neq m$. Take $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}\vert l – m\vert$
. For large enough n,
$\vert a_n – l\vert  < ε$, $\vert a_n – m| < ε$.
From the triangle inequality, $l – m \lt 2ε = l – m$, which is not the case.
How was triangle inequality used to get
$l – m \lt 2ε = l – m$ from $\vert a_n – l\vert  < ε$ and $\vert a_n – m| < ε$ ?

\begin{align} 
l-m \ &= \ l - a_n + a_n - m \ \leq \ |l - a_n +  a_n - m | \ \overset{\text{T.I.}}{\leq} \ |l - a_n | + |  a_n -m | \\ \\
&= \ |a_n - l | + |  a_n - m | \ < \ \varepsilon + \varepsilon \ = \ 2 \varepsilon 
\end{align}
where first we add and subtract $a_n$ and then we use the triangular inequality (T.I.) to separate the two terms which we are able to estimate.

If $|a_n-l|<\varepsilon$ and $|a_n-m|<\varepsilon$, then
\begin{align}
|l-m|&=|(a_n-m)-(a_n-l)|\\
&<\varepsilon+\varepsilon\\
&=2\varepsilon.
\end{align}
